# Best way to check if sharing via SLComposeViewController is successful with a limited (or no) Internet connection

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-share-extension

[Apple's documentation is clear](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/) on using SLComposeViewController to provide sharing capabilites with other social networks such as Twitter and Facebook.

Typical code will use `isAvailableForServiceType` to verify if a particular service is available and then add a completion handler to the view controller where an `SLComposeViewControllerResult` can be checked for either `SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled` or `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone`, which check if the user tapped on the 'Post' button or on the 'Cancel' button after the sharing view has been displayed.

The issue here is that if you use `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` to validate that the user made the request, you don't actually check if it was successful such as when the user has limited or no connectivity.

I have tried with one of my apps to test this and have noticed that the `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` constant is still valid even if airplane mode is turned on such that a request is not possible. What this means is that the user fills out the sharing view fields and taps on 'Post' and my *success* code executes even though I should really be checking to make sure that the post was indeed successful.

Currently, I figure that the best option is to check for an Internet connection using the standard Reachability options ([as recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411324/facebook-sharing-with-slcomposeviewcontroller-prevent-completion-handler-when-n)) and disable the sharing button if a connection is not available, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution as it doesn't account for a limited connection where the user can tap on 'Post' but the actual request is unsuccessful.

My question is **what is the best method of detecting if a sharing request has successfully completed**?

Comment: you have created your own `Share-Extension`, where you want to check the success, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

then you need to make sure that you do not write below line in `didSelectPost`

```
[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:nil completionHandler:nil];
```

and once you get success or fail based on that in the your request handler you can write above line, so your `didSelectPost` should be like :

```
- (void)didSelectPost {
    NSExtensionItem *inputItem = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
    NSItemProvider *attachment = inputItem.attachments.firstObject;
    if ([attachment hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.url"])
    {
        //NSString *strLink = [attachement loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.url" options:nil completionHandler:nil];
        [attachment loadItemForTypeIdentifier: @"public.url"
                                       options: nil
           // make your request here
        }];
    }
}
```